# Where is org.geotools.data.postgis?

Tags: java, maven, postgis, geotools

I'm trying to import WKBReader by including `import org.geotools.data.postgis.WKBReader;`.

The WKBReader class should be in `org.geotools.data.postgis` [according to the documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/postgis/WKBReader.html), but package is not available for me.

I tried to add the gt-postgis repository to `pom.xml` as:

```
<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <geotools.version>17.1</geotools.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-postgis</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency> 
...
```

...but with no luck. I always get errors like:

> Failed to execute goal on project tutorial: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.geotools:tutorial:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-postgis:jar:17.1 in http://download.java.net/maven/2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

My question: where is `org.geotools:gt-postgis:jar:17.1`?

My complete pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
   <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <name>tutorial</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <geotools.version>17.1</geotools.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net repository</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      </repository>

      <repository>
          <id>osgeo</id>
          <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
          <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
      </repository>

      <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>opengeo</id>
        <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
      </repository> 
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart.GeoJson2Shape</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

mvn log:

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.530 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-04T12:22:50+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/299M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project tutorial: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /data/osm/maven/geotools/tutorial/src/main/java/org/geotools/tutorial/quickstart/WKB2Shape.java:[30,33] package org.geotools.data.postgis does not exist
[ERROR] /data/osm/maven/geotools/tutorial/src/main/java/org/geotools/tutorial/quickstart/WKB2Shape.java:[56,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WKBReader
[ERROR] location: class org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart.WKB2Shape
[ERROR] /data/osm/maven/geotools/tutorial/src/main/java/org/geotools/tutorial/quickstart/WKB2Shape.java:[56,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WKBReader
[ERROR] location: class org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart.WKB2Shape
[ERROR] /data/osm/maven/geotools/tutorial/src/main/java/org/geotools/tutorial/quickstart/WKB2Shape.java:[58,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Geometry

[ERROR] location: class org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart.WKB2Shape
```

Comment: I think you put a wrong URL try to replace it with: http://repo.opengeo.org/ and build again. I think it will work.

Comment: Have you checked the geotools website? Specifically the maven quickstart? http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html

Comment: Yes, i checked quickstart (even installed it and got it running)

Comment: and i do read a lot of documentation - yes i do!

but there is of course no information which classes/methods are in which packet. e.g that i need gt-geojson to process geojson data.

Comment: @fady repo.opengeo.org not added, because it allready exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) shows you need the following in your pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: did upvote, but you can't see it. ok, accept worked.